# Hide "No custom tool available" window

Tags: unity

I have this annoying window in the bottom right of the scene view.  From the manual, it seems like I opened it by clicking on the wrench & scribe button next to the movement buttons.

[image: No custom tools available]

How do I make it do away now?

Restarting doesn't make a difference, neither does creating a brand new project.

The [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingCustomEditorTools.html) say this appears it I've clicked on the tools icon and there aren't any custom tools (which I'm sure I have done).  Surely is should vanish after a while though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **two** buttons with the crossed tools.  Clicking the smaller button at the right side of the Scene View (near the *Gizmos* button) hides the window:

[image]